# Can't launch composer update

Tags: php, symfony

I tried successfuly those commands :

```
php composer.phar require sonata-project/user-bundle --no-update
php composer.phar require sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle  --no-update
php composer.phar require friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle  --no-update
php composer.phar require nelmio/api-doc-bundle  --no-update
```

but when I try to update composer like that :

```
php composer.phar update
```

I have the following error message :

> Loading composer repositories with package information Updating
>   dependencies (including require-dev) Your requirements could not be
>   resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>   - sonata-project/user-bundle 3.0.1 requires friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle ^1. 1 -> satisfiable by
>   friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle[1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.3 .0,
>   1.3.1, 1.4.0, 1.4.0-RC1, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.5.0, 1.5.0-RC1, 1.5.0-RC2, 1.5.0-RC 3, 1.5.0-RC4, 1.5.0-RC5, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.x-dev, 1.6.0, 1.6.0-RC1, 1.6.0
>   -RC2, 1.6.1, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.6, 1.7.7, 1.7.8, 1.7.9, 1.7. x-dev, 1.8.0, 1.8.0-BETA1, 1.8.0-BETA2, 1.8.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>   - sonata-project/user-bundle 3.0.0 requires friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle ^1. 1 -> satisfiable by
>   friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle[1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.3 .0,
>   1.3.1, 1.4.0, 1.4.0-RC1, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.5.0, 1.5.0-RC1, 1.5.0-RC2, 1.5.0-RC 3, 1.5.0-RC4, 1.5.0-RC5, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.x-dev, 1.6.0, 1.6.0-RC1, 1.6.0
>   -RC2, 1.6.1, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.6, 1.7.7, 1.7.8, 1.7.9, 1.7. x-dev, 1.8.0, 1.8.0-BETA1, 1.8.0-BETA2, 1.8.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>   - Installation request for sonata-project/user-bundle ^3.0 -> satisfiable by sonata-project/user-bundle[3.0.0, 3.0.1].

I use Symfony3 if that help and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is not supported on Symfony 3.x right now:

https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/issues/724

I also tried your commands above and tried removing and different versions of FOSRest, etc... to no avail.

Suggest you try going to Symfony version 2.8 instead if you can do that...

Answer (score 0):

Work greate !! thanks ! I used symfony version 2.8 instead and I added this command :

```
php composer.phar update friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle 1.1
```

I use the version 1.1 instead of 2.3